# Z-Order of PopupWindow

Tags: mfc

I Created a LayerdWindow with WS_POPUP prpoerty set..
But I am not able to set it's Z-Order by SetWindowPos..This windows is always coming on the top of other windows. I want it below to a particular window..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are not calling SetWindowPos() from the thread where you created the window. Use the same thread or try this flag:

**SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS**
If the calling thread and the thread that owns the window are attached to different input queues, the system posts the request to the thread that owns the window. This prevents the calling thread from blocking its execution while other threads process the request.